# NASM x64: trying to scanf a character and compare it to the letter 'y'

Tags: char, 64-bit, scanf, nasm, cmp

I'm programming a number guessing game in NASM x64 assembly but I have hit a snag at the end. I ask the user "Do you want to play again?(y or n): " and of course use scanf to get the character. When I use "%c" as the format, it just skips scanf completely. When I try to input it as a decimal, and compare it to the letter 'y', it doesn't work. It works when I just use 1 instead of y though.

I define the letter 'y' under the data section as:
`yes: dd 'y'`

This is the code for the scanf and comparison:

```
    mov rdi, fmt   ;expect char (tried decimal too)
    mov rsi, playagain  ;input variable (playagain: resb 1)
    mov al, 0     ;no float 
    call scanf

    ;comparison
    mov rcx, [playagain]  ;move to register to compare
    cmp rcx, [yes]       ;the letter 'y'
    je play             ;back to the beginning
```

I hope that was descriptive enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking the *address* of the variable that you use to receive the result of the `scanf` call, not the content.

Before the call to `scanf`, you correctly do `mov rsi, playagain`, but after the call, you have to do `mov rcx, [playagain]`.

In addition, as scanf only stores 1 byte when the `%c` format is used, you should compare only one byte (`cmp cl, [yes]`), or initialise `playagain` the same way as you initialize `yes`.

I.e.the following should work:

```
section .data
fmt:       db '%c',0
playagain: dd 'n'     ; db is enough, but change comparison accordingly
yes:       dd 'y'

section .text 
play:  
    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, playagain
    mov al, 0      
    call scanf

    ;comparison
    mov ecx, [playagain]  
    cmp ecx, [yes]        ; don't compare more bytes than used for the vars      
    je play
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have done what you outlined above but it still seems to do the same thing. I'm not exactly sure if I'm defining the letter y correctly (I've tried yes: dd 121, yes: dd 'y', yes: dw 0x79, etc), and I don't know what to use for the format of scanf (%c skips input, %d doesn't work). Everything works fine if I just use the number 1 instead of 'y'. Amazing how the most simple thing in C becomes so hard in asm.

Comment: %c reads one character, (one byte), so dont' compare more than that unless you initialize the buffer the same way as you initialize `yes`. See my edits.